# Not able to set the value for td element of table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to edit set the value of a column in a particular row in a table and the code is not working.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```js
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hi'));
$('#tr').appendChild(td);
```

```html
<tr id="tr">
  <td >
    Row 3
  </td>
  <!--- In the middle of these 2 row, i want that column that says "hi"-->
  <td>
    Row 3
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** Only when you wrap it correctly inside a `<table>`, this would work.

I don't think `$` is defined. So you might need to use the `td`.

```html
<table>
  <tr id="tr">
    <td >
      Row 3
    </td>
    <!--- In the middle of these 2 row, i want that column that says "hi"-->
    <td>
      Row 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hi'));
  var el = document.getElementById("tr").getElementsByTagName("td");
  el[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<td>' + td.innerHTML + '</td>');
</script>
```

If you are using jQuery, it is very simple, but you need to wrap your `<tr>` inside `<table>` in order for the `<tr>` to be displayed. Check the **working snippet** below:

```js
$(function () {
  var td = $("<td />", {
    html: "hi"
  });
  $("#tr").find("td").first().after(td);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr">
    <td >
      Row 3
    </td>
    <!--- In the middle of these 2 row, i want that column that says "hi"-->
    <td>
      Row 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In your answer, you did not write "var" while declaring the variable "el"

Answer (score 0):

To append it in second position :

```
 $('#tr td').first().after(td);
```

What the point of  mixing native javascript with jquery ?
I would do it like that :

```
var td = $('<td>').text('hi');
$('#tr td').first().after(td);
```